# How to add items without its default namespace in collection editor?

Tags: c#, windows, winforms

I have created a custom collection and collectioneditor for the collection and when i add new item to the collection through Add button in collectioneditor, the collectioneditor shows the item as whole with namespaces as below,

**WindowsFormApplication.MyApplication.MyItem
WindowsFormApplication.MyApplication.MyItem**

Is there any way to add the item without showing the namespace and like below,

**MyItem1
MyItem2**

Could anyone please let me know?

Comment: Override the ToString method to return MyItem value.

Comment: @loneshark99 - Thanks for your solution.

Comment: Does it work for you ?

Comment: Yes, its working. I have overrided the ToString() for my requirement

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When displaying a collection .Net will by default call the object's `.ToString()` method. This method will by default just return the objects fully qualified class name. If you want a different presentation you need to override the `.ToString()` method of your class.

For example:

```
public override String ToString()
{
    return this.Label;
}
```